# My Public projects Microsoft-hosted 0 Parallel jobs

Tags: azure-devops

[image]

There are no 10 parallel jobs now ?

Comment: Hi @caoyufei, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we create new projects in new Azure DevOps organizations, we will see the number of Public Parallel jobs is 0.

New public projects created in Azure DevOps will no longer get a free grant of concurrent pipelines. As a result, you won’t be able to run pipelines when you create a new public project.

Note: This change does not impact our existing open-source or public project users. It only impacts new projects that you create in new Azure DevOps organizations.

As a workaround, we could send email to request the free grant of parallel jobs in Azure Pipelines.

You could check this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-public-projects/)`(email content and address)` for more details.